# Junit tests run locally (commandline+maven) but not on jenkins; Failed to load ApplicationContext IllegalArgumentException: InputStream cannot be null

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jenkins, spring-security, junit

I am working on an app and in parallel we set up the ci/cd environment. The app has 3 basic junit tests at the moment.

coordinates: java 17, spring boot2, h2 db, saml, vaadin, maven 3.9.1, jenkins was updated last week to current version.

The tests run in my ide but not on the jenkins. I made sure to use the same (java+maven) versions as the jenkins 17.0.2/ 3.9.1) and ran maven clean install on the command line; working fine locally. Does not run on the jenkins.

basic test example:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class Core2ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    //system sanity test
    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

I expected the tests to run, but over on the jenkins it reads

[ERROR] contextLoads  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< ERROR!

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream cannot be null

```
         at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:118) ~[na:na]

         at org.opensaml.xml.parse.BasicParserPool$DocumentBuilderProxy.parse(BasicParserPool.java:712) ~[xmltooling-1.4.6.jar:na]

         at org.opensaml.xml.parse.BasicParserPool.parse(BasicParserPool.java:221) ~[xmltooling-1.4.6.jar:na]

         at org.opensaml.xml.XMLConfigurator.load(XMLConfigurator.java:142) ~[xmltooling-1.4.6.jar:1.4.6]

         at org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap.initializeXMLTooling(DefaultBootstrap.java:224) ~[opensaml-2.6.6.jar:1.0.10.RELEASE]

         at org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap.initializeXMLTooling(DefaultBootstrap.java:207) ~[opensaml-2.6.6.jar:1.0.10.RELEASE]

         at org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap(DefaultBootstrap.java:100) ~[opensaml-2.6.6.jar:1.0.10.RELEASE]

         at org.opensaml.PaosBootstrap.bootstrap(PaosBootstrap.java:27) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.10.RELEASE.jar:1.0.10.RELEASE]

         at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap.postProcessBeanFactory(SAMLBootstrap.java:42) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.10.RELEASE.jar:1.0.10.RELEASE]

         at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:325) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]

         at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:198) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]

         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]

         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]

         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]

         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]

         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]

         at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:136) ~[spring-boot-test-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]

         at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:141) ~[spring-test-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]

         at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:90) ~[spring-test-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
```

Does anybody have an idea, what is going on at the jenkins? Any help would be appreciated. The only involved files are under src/main/resources, so there is no obvious reason for me why locally the tests run and the server misses "something". Except, afterer having read some of the suggested answers: I wondered why these tests run anyway, because I was used to thinking that everything that needs an environment has at least to be mocked. And JUnit tests were not really made for the purpose of running on the server. Right or wrong?

Comment: did you commit/push all the files?

Comment: Yes. I started the project, ok, but 2 colleagues which started to work on it recently pulled it from git and "mvn install" is also working on their machines locally. So the files are all there.

Comment: It looks like this piece of code is being called: https://github.com/korteke/java-opensaml/blob/master/opensaml-core/src/main/java/org/opensaml/core/xml/config/XMLConfigurator.java#L129-L150 If you change the loglevel to debug for this class, you should be able to see the problematic file.